# Passing an object reference to a jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

(Notice to moderators : I have read and understood this excellent thread : [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) and it is not related to this question)

I **didn't found a similar case mixing jQuery and OOP** to pass a context to a jQuery callback.

I defined a class named *MySlider* and a method named *registerListener*s on it,
but I fail to get the reference to the *MySlider* object from a jQuery callback.

Any idea?

```
MySlider.prototype.registerListeners = function () {
    var hello = this;
    $('#sl').slider({
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(event + " " + ui);

            // how to access 'hello' from here ?
        }
    }) ;
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `console.log(hello);`?

Comment: It should just be accessed as `hello`. That’s how proxies work anyway.

Comment: thank you, sometimes javacript is so complicated that the simpliest solution is supposed to fail. Shame on me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object oriented programming and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163021/object-oriented-programming-and-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Just access it! You've created a closure, where a variable defined in an outer function is accessed from an inner function.

A sort of copy of the variable is stored with the function object. If you did `var hello = "tricked you!"` after you'd defined your function, the value of `hello` found in your inner function would update to match.